# Distance between vectors with missing values

Tags: r, distance

For vectors `A` and `B`, euclidean distance is:`sqrt((A1-B1)^2+(A2-B2)^2+...+(An-Bn)^2)`

```
A <- c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5)
B <- c(1, 0, 6, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3)
dist(rbind(A,B), method= "euclidean") 
7.681146
```

How is distance calculated when vectors A and B contain missing values? Here is an example: R output for distance is `8.485281` but how is it calculated?

```
A <- c(5, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5)
B <- c(1, 0, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 3)
dist(rbind(A,B), method= "euclidean")
8.485281
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Entries with `NA` are first removed, then the distance is scaled up to account for the larger dimension of the full sample:

```
i <- is.na(A) | is.na(B)
dist(rbind(A[!i], B[!i])) * sqrt(length(A) / length(A[!i]))
#          A2
# B2 8.485281
```